# Linking 'Display Name' in Bio

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks, rules

I've tried to link my name (my 'display name' is the same as my 'real name') in the 'about me' box of the user page to my personal site, but it gets removed. Other links in my bio work just fine. Is there some kind of rule that disallows linking the text of your name in a bio?

If so, what's the reasoning?

*Edited from 'bio' to 'about me', called it that because it generates the autobiographer badge.*

**Update**: Should have just kept trying different things. From what I can tell, a link with the `href` in a single quote does not work, but in double quotes works just fine. Maybe a markdown issue a wasn't aware of?

Comment: You're referencing Careers?

Comment: No, any of the trilogy sites. The 'about me' section allows links for other words, but will not let me link my name. Just seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see

[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

which is linked from the [Markdown FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) at the bottom.

Comment: Yup, I checked the page, but didn't take the 'exactly as shown' (or should it be "exactly as shown") seriously enough. Okay, to be honest, I guess it was because I didn't scroll past seeing the href tag.

Comment: But you disallow `TITLE` in the About Me section don't you?

Comment: Title works for me. With double quotes of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is clearly broken, since [mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22459/olafur-waage) works.

```
<a href="http://www.cznp.com">Ólafur Waage</a>
```

Comment: Joo arr ah spjelling natsi!

Comment: At least it wasn't You're's